# Created nested json using python dictionaries

Tags: python

i have for loops running on the multiple levels . Each level of loop returns a json which needs to be put in a hierarchy .

```
output = {}
for a in alist:
  aid, ajson = hit_api(url1)
  output[aid] = ajson
  for b in blist:
    bid, bjson = hit_api(url2)
    output[aid][bid] = bjson -- this is where we are getting error
```

The error is as below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 80, in <module>
    output[aid][bid] = bjson 
TypeError: 'unicode' object does not support item assignment
```

We need to create a final json with nested hierarchy based on the for loop.
something like

```
aid:ajson 
  |
  ---bid:bjson
      |
       --- cid:cjson
             |
             etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `ajson` is a string. You might want to parse this. You can use python standard library [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) and call `json.loads(ajson)`

Example:

```
import json
output = {}
for a in alist:
  aid, ajson = hit_api(url1)
  output[aid] = json.loads(ajson)
  for b in blist:
    bid, bjson = hit_api(url2)
    output[aid][bid] = json.loads(bjson)
```

Comment: yeah.. all jsons are string.. but i dont want jsons to be on same hierarchy.. i want , bjson to be nested under ajson .

Comment: But still i end up in error
    output[aid] = json.load(str(ajson))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 286, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Sorry, it should be `json.loads`, not `json.load`. I have updated answer